# Alternative for Django-Tinymce-editor

Tags: django-tinymce

I used django-tinymce in my project. The django-tinymce editor is appended on textarea field  using "tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id); " command but the problem is that it does't have image upload functionality from local machine. please suggest me which editor suits in my condition.

Comment: I resolved the problem using jquery-easyui-1.3.4 and my code as bellow<form id="my_form" action="/quiz/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {%csrf_token%}
    
    <input id="image" name="image" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </form>and my script <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#my_form').form({
        success:function(data){
                tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent("<img src='"+data+"' />"); 
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery-easyui-1.3.4 example is below

```
<form id="my_form" action="/quiz/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    {%csrf_token%}  
    <input id="image" name="image" type="file" /> <input type="submit" value="upload" />
```

and my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(function(){ $('#my_form').form({ success:function(data){  
     tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent("<img src='"+data+"' />"); } }); 
     });
```